# on ng-click i want to navigate to another state dynamically

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="menu in sideMenuList" class="item item-icon-left" menu-close ng-click="$state.go("{{menu.url}}")">
 {{menu.displayName}}
</ion-item>
```

In menu.url i have different state for example app.home,app.products.When i click menu.displayname it should navigate based on menu.url

- List item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **uiSref** directive:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="menu in sideMenuList" class="item item-icon-left" menu-close ui-sref="menu.url">
 {{menu.displayName}}
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="menu in sideMenuList" class="item item-icon-left" menu-close ng-click="$state.go(menu.url)">
   {{menu.displayName}}
</ion-item>
```